# HttpListener won't work over network even with firewall allowed

Tags: c#, networking, webserver, firewall, httplistener

I'm using the following code to add a http listener:

```cs
public class WebServer
{
    private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
    private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, HttpListenerResponse, string> _responderMethod;

    public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, HttpListenerResponse, string> method)
    {
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

        // URI prefixes are required, for example 
        // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

        // A responder method is required
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("method");

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
            _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

        _responderMethod = method;
        _listener.Start();
    }

    public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, HttpListenerResponse, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
        : this(prefixes, method) { }

    public void Run()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
            try
            {
                while (_listener.IsListening)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                    {
                        var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                        try
                        {
                            string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request, ctx.Response);
                            byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        }
                        catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                        finally
                        {
                            // always close the stream
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                        }
                    }, _listener.GetContext());
                }
            }
            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
        _listener.Close();
    }
}

static class Program
{
    public const int PORT = 18991;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://+:" + PORT + "/");
        ws.Run();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        ws?.Stop();
    }
    private static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request, HttpListenerResponse response)
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

This works fine on the local machine, however it won't listen to request from other devices inside the network. I even added a <del>outgoing</del> incoming rule to the firewall allowing the connection, I added the URL using `netsh http add urlacl url="http://+:18991/" user=everyone` and started the application with admin rights, but no success.

How can I allow requests from remote devices inside the LAN?

Comment: `I even added a outgoing rule to the firewall`. Don't you think it should be an *incoming* rule...

Comment: @Eser Sorry, my mistake. I meant, I added an _incoming_ rule to the firewall.

Comment: `however it won't listen to request from other devices inside the network.` What error do you get (both, on server and client side)?

Comment: @Eser No error, just a timeout on the requesting device, and no error in the application.

Comment: Can you ping the server? Can you connect to servers port(for ex using telnet)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Comment: @Eser I currently can't test pinging the server or connecting to it via telnet as I do not have a secondary computer, but only my phone.

Comment: Make the necessaty NAT settings on your modem/switch/router....., we can test it here... Or good luck....

Comment: @Eser I just want this application to communicate inside my LAN so no need to change any router settings.

Comment: Of course, but given info doesn't help us enough... As I said, good luck...

Comment: I have recently implement HTTPS using HTTPListener and allow communication over LAN as well by add firewall rule. There is no any input required, everything is handled by C# code. I have shared my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58149405/983548

Answer (score 5):

Here are steps that you can try and see if they help:

1. Start Visual Studio as administrator:

   [image: Start Visual Studio]
2. Start your application in debug mode.
3. Open *Resource Monitor* in Windows and ensure that the port is present and set to *Allowed, not restricted*:

   [image: Resource monitor]
4. If not, add an inbound firewall rule for the port:

   [image]

   Allow it on all domains:

   [image]

   Allow programs:

   [image]

   Allow the connection:

   [image]
5. Start `HttpListener` in the following way:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpTestServer
{
    public class MainWindow
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _httpListener;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            _httpListener = new HttpListener();
            _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:9191/");
            Task.Run(Start);
        }

        public async Task Start()
        {
            _httpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var context = await _httpListener.GetContextAsync();

                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
                {
                    await sw.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

6. Run `ipconfig` and check what IP address you have:

   [image]
7. Ping your computer from the other computer on the network:

   [image]
8. From the other computer, also test to send an HTTP request to your computer:

   [image]